# document.getElementById("id").innerHTML run time error on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7, struts

I wrote an AJAX function and with this function I am populating the `<option>` tag of a particular `<select>` tag. This function runs fine on all leading web browsers but when I try to run it on IE7 it gives me the runtime error on following line in the browser:

```
document.getElementById("box2View").innerHTML = req.responseText;
```

My code is

```
   function retrieveURL(url)
   {
    var newUrl = 'showStates.do?country='+url; 

    req = GetXmlHttpObject();
    req.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
    try {
         req.open("GET", newUrl, true);
    } catch (e) {
         alert(e);
    }
    req.send();

   }
   function processStateChange() {

        if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete
            if (req.status == 200) { // OK response
                alert(req.responseText);
                document.getElementById("box2View").innerHTML = req.responseText;

                var x = document.getElementsByName("countryid");

            } else {
             alert("Problem: " + req.statusText);
            }
        }
    }



    function GetXmlHttpObject()
       {
        var xmlHttp=null;
        try
         {
         // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
         xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
        catch (e)
         {
           //Internet Explorer
           try
            {
              xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
              xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            }
       return xmlHttp;           

       }
```

When I debug it I found that I got a HTML from in `req.responseText` 
which is[image: here]

So can anyone tell me what should I do to make it work with IE7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest won't work in IE 7/8 but works in other browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418403/xmlhttprequest-wont-work-in-ie-7-8-but-works-in-other-browsers)